# View for version control (git) status with full file names

Tags: files, git

Tools > Version control > Git > Status produces nice interactive output to browse the repository.

Is there any way however to have full path names of the modified files, which can be textually copy-pasted somewhere else, or is the only option to run `git status` from the command line and copy paste from there?

The use case is that I want to store the paths for later in a text file, visit them (I have file at point automation, making go to file hypertext experience) possibly while in another branch, etc.

That is, something analogous to C-x C-b list for the currently open buffers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're open to a new tool, [Magit](https://github.com/magit/magit) has this baked in. If you invoke `magit-status` while visiting a file that's part of a git repo, Magit's default view will show you the path from the project root of each modified file (I believe this is customizable). If you put point on a modified file and hit `C-w`, the path will be added to the kill ring.

My approach to storing paths for later would probably be based around [magit integration with Org](https://github.com/emacsattic/org-magit), particularly `org-store-link` or `org-capture`. (Full disclosure, I have not set this up myself yet -- and it would require both Magit and Org Mode, so may not suit your use case.

Comment: Thanks. I am open to using new tool, but can't install it through packages at the moment as it requires emacs 24.4 while I am at 24.3.1... (and there are 5 other packages needed). Possibly, will try it at some later time when Emacs default git options will not be enough any more.

Comment: Ahh, blast. Wish I could be more help.